# If condition not being respected

Tags: c

i'm having a problem with the following code:

```
/* 
 * Esercizio 5
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getProduct(char product[]);
long getNumber(char product[]);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char product1[60] = {0};
    char product2[60] = {0};
    char product3[60] = {0};
    char productInput[60] = {0};

    int flag = 0;
    long cost = 0;

    printf("Product 1: ");
    gets(product1);
    printf("Product 2: ");
    gets(product2);
    printf("Product 3: ");
    gets(product3);

    do {

        printf("Product and quantity: ");
        gets(productInput);
        printf("productInput: %s\n", getProduct(productInput));
        printf("product1: %s\n", getProduct(product1));
        if(getProduct(product1) == getProduct(productInput)){ /* PROBLEM HERE!!! */

            // No matter what i input it always goes here
            printf("Selezionato prodotto 1");
            cost = getNumber(product1) * getNumber(productInput);
            flag = 1;

        } else if(getProduct(product2) == getProduct(productInput)){

            printf("Selezionato prodotto 1");
            cost = getNumber(product2) * getNumber(productInput);
            flag = 1;

        } else if(getProduct(product3) == getProduct(productInput)){

            printf("Selezionato prodotto 1");
            cost = getNumber(product3) * getNumber(productInput);
            flag = 1;

        }

    }  while(!flag);

    printf("Costo totale: %d", cost);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char* getProduct(char product[]){

    char *pointer;
    char str_product[60] = {0};

    strcpy(str_product, product);

    pointer = strtok(str_product, " ");

    return pointer;

}

long getNumber(char product[]){

    char *pointer;
    char str_product[60] = {0};

    strcpy(str_product, product);

    pointer = strtok(str_product, " ");
    pointer = strtok(NULL, " ");

    return strtol(pointer, NULL, 10);

}
```

As you can clearly see, `getProduct(productInput)` and `getProduct(product1)` return pointers to different values. The problem is that even if values are different the `if` condition is not being respected.

Comment: Seems like you need to step through your code (debug)

Comment: [at]Keyser That's why i added two printf inside do-while cycle
@Amadan I put the whole code because i need to display how those functions work and i highlighted where the problem is happening with a comment.

Comment: @ShadowBroker: No, you don't need to do display that. We didn't need to know about `cost`, or `flag`, or `getNumber`, or most of the `printf` statements. All that - noise. I never saw the comment, since it too was buried in three pages of code. It would have helped if you said at the top "Relevant line is marked in the code", but even then you're not excused from making your code a minimal example. This time there were some kind people that persisted enough to help you; next time maybe there won't. Concise but complete questions get much better chance of getting answered.

Comment: If you do an actual "@" sign, I get notified. Just so you know. Still, the if-statement is obviously working. If you step through the code you can see exactly what's being compared, not what you **think** is being compared. In this case, references instead of values. It's a good way to handle these kind of errors that won't get solved by reading the code again and again and again :p

Comment: @Keyser I can't add more than one "@" in each comment.

Comment: @ShadowBroker That's true :p Missed your second one since I was first :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to compare strings by the `==` operator, which is not doing what you expect it to do.

Instead you need to compare them by calling `strcmp()` (or better yet, `strncmp()`)

```
if(strmcp(getProduct(product1), getProduct(productInput)) == 0){
```

The reason why comparing strings by `==` does not work properly is that `==` compares the pointers (basically, the memory location where the strings are stored), not the strings themselves

Comment: Thank you... i think i did too much PHP programming :)

Comment: The problem still persists, even after your solution. I think i know why. Actually the `getProduct` function returns a pointer that is not pointing to the argument i pass when i call the function but the the `str_product` variable that is located inside the `getProduct` function.
I'm using `str_product` as a copy of the product parameter because `strtok` modifies the string and i don't want that to happen.

Comment: @ShadowBroker - You are correct, and this is a classic case of dangling pointers.  You need to pass a copy of the string to `getProduct` instead of it making the copy.